# XPATH Get child elements Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, xpath

I have this XML:

```html
<dl>
  <number>1</number>
  <ref>r54</ref>
</dl>
 
<dl>
  <number>2</number>
  <ref>r67</ref>
</dl>
  
<dl>
  <number>3</number>
  <ref>r89</ref>
</dl>
```

I need to store Dl in an array which contains all the child values of the dl.
My output should be:

```html
dl: {
  number: 1,
  ref: r54
},
dl {
  number: 1,
  ref: r67
},
dl {
  number: 1,
  ref: r89
},
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```js
public getArrayDl(xml: Document, xpath: string) {
  let array = [];
  let i = 0;
  let nodes = xml.evaluate(xpath, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  let result = nodes.iterateNext();
  while (result) {
   array[i] =  result.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   result = nodes.iterateNext();
   i++;
  }
 
  return array;

 }
```

But it is isn't working, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What value are you using for the xpath? That information will allow us to try and run your code.

Comment: You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) instead of xpath

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are trying to convert XML segments to JSON.

There are a number of XML to JSON libraries available.

- [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)
- [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json)
- [x2js](https://github.com/abdmob/x2js)
- or, if you insist, [role your own](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)..

Make use of them, e.g. x2js

```js
var xmlString  = `<root><dl><number>1</number><ref>r54</ref></dl><dl><number>2</number><ref>r67</ref></dl><dl><number>3</number><ref>r89</ref></dl></root>`;

var x2js = new X2JS();
//console.log(x2js.xml_str2json(xmlString));

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

var arr = [];
let nodes = xmlDoc.evaluate("//*[dl]", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
let result = nodes.iterateNext();
while (result) {
  arr.push(x2js.xml2json (result));
  result = nodes.iterateNext();
}

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x2js/1.2.0/xml2json.js"></script>
```

PS: I wrapped the dl segments with a `<root>` tag to make it valid XML. Something to keep in mind, or iterate over the individual segments.

Comment: I would like to add [fast-xml-parser](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/) in the above list for the sake of speed and customization options.

Comment: Does https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/ support xpath?