# How to insert html element with only XPath given?

Tags: html, typescript, xpath

I'm writing a web extension in Typescript.

I want to insert a custom element at the end of a `div` element on the page. But the `div` does not have an id. The only way I can think of addressing it is with the XPath:

`/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div`

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: can you please share the html of div and it's parent div.

Comment: May be something you can salvage from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52465472/xpath-get-child-elements-typescript-javascript

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver You can select the element by XPath.